# PHP mysqli not adding column (ALTER TABLE) via a variable

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to add a column to a table using following code. It is not letting me to insert column name via a variable ($document_type).

```
$document_type=$_POST['document_type'];
$category=$_POST['category'];
$file_extension=$_POST['file_extension'];

// Database Insert
$sql_link = Connect_MySQLi_DB();
$stmt1 = $sql_link->prepare("INSERT INTO document_type (document_type,category,file_extension) VALUES (?,?,?)"); 
$stmt1->bind_param('sss',$document_type,$category,$file_extension);

if($stmt1->execute()){
//Problem Here
$sql_link->query("ALTER TABLE hr_types ADD $document_type VARCHAR(255) NULL"); 
}
```

If I type column name statically it works. But with the variable, noting happens, it does not even throw an error. Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: Variable is passing properly. It's bizarre, for some reason Yash Sodha's answer worked. Can anyone explain?

Comment: It was backticks. I just wrap `hr_types` and `$document_type` with backticks and started working like a magic. It actually worked without {..}. I think mysql reserved keywords involved here.

Comment: It was spaces in the Variable data!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work. :)

```
$sql_link->query("ALTER TABLE `hr_types` ADD `{$document_type}` varchar(255) NULL");
```

Comment: You are awesome. It works! But how did that happen? Could you please explain?

Comment: Well the backticks are purely SQL syntax (and if your query worked without, it's unlikely those solved it although it is always good to use them). First you had `$document_type` - what if PHP knows a variable by the name `$document`, would you like it here? Well, why not? By adding `{..}` you force to use the full variable name

Comment: It was backticks. I just wrap `hr_types` and `$document_type` with backticks and started working like a magic. It actually worked without {..}. I think mysql reserved keywords involved here.

Comment: but {...} is preferred.

Comment: `"$var_123"` gets interpolated to `$var_123`, not `$var."_123"`

Comment: Yes. It was spaces in the variable data !